# How to run a node app in another machine without nodemon installed as global

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I am building an app using nodejs and express framework and have installed nodemon globally to restart the server automatically.

Now if I take this app and run in another machine/host/environment (without nodemon installed globally) then it would produce an error because package.json doesn't contain nodemon as a dependency.

What would be the best way to fix this?

Comment: Actually, you just need to run node index.js as usual. If you still want to run nodemon, so you can install nodemon locally on project by `npm i nodemon`.

Answer (score 0):

Include nodemon in your package.json as a dev dependency. So it will be available in the context of the script.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon my_file.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "<version>",
  }
}
```

Then from the terminal you can use `npm start`

Answer (score 0):

Nodemon has been the goto for a long time, but now with Node.js 19, we have `--watch` flag, which restarts server when files changes. Keep in mind this is experimental
[Docs](https://Running%20in%20%E2%80%98watch%E2%80%99%20mode%20restarts%20the%20process%20when%20an%20imported%20file%20is%20changed.)
:)